# Should naming of methods within interfaces be concrete or abstract?

Tags: interface, naming-conventions, method-names

Often when I create new classes, I first create a new interface. I name the methods of my interface exactly as I would like them to behave. A colleague of mine prefers to have these method names being more abstract, ie: areConditionsMet(). The reason, he wants to hide the 'implementation details'.

IMO implementation details are different from the expected behavior. Could anyone perhaps give more insight. My goal is to reach a common ground with my colleague.

Comment: What would be your name for 'areConditionsMet'?

Comment: If I had two conditions: Lets say the Domain Object must be modified (ie flag is set to true) and it has certain properties. My name would be isDomainObjectModifiedAndHasProperties(). The difficulty is that some classes are more abstract than others. Some helper/manager classes do exactly that what the method describes. But the more abstract you get, I can imagine you would eventually end up with an interface, with method "doesDomainObjectSatisfyCriteria".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method names should describe what the method does, but not how it does it.  The example you gave is a pretty poor method name, but it's better than `isXGreatherThan1AndLessThan6()`.  Without knowing the details about what it should do, I would say that it should be specific to the problem at hand, but general enough that the implementation could change without affecting the name itself, i.e., you don't want the name of the method to be brittle.  An example might be `isTemperatureWithinRange()`  - that describes what I'm checking but doesn't describe how it's accomplished.  The user of the method should be confident that the output will reflect whether the temperature is within a certain range -- whether this is supplied as an argument or defined by the contract of the class, is immaterial.

Answer (score 0):

The names of your interface methods should leave the user of the interface in *no doubt* about what the method proposes to do from a functional perspective. If the implementation matches that, well and good.

Based on your updated comments:

Sounds to me like you need two methods: **isModified()** and **hasProperties()**. Leave it up to the user (or higher layer) of the domain object to determine if a particular criteria is fulfilled.

An interface should also be designed with the view that after it is released it will **never** be changed. By saying isDomainObjectModifiedAndHasProperties() you are setting in concrete that this is *the* criteria of fullfilment (regardless of any future unforseen implementation).

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces should represent some behavior or capability and not the way it is to be accomplished. Users of interfaces should not be interested in the way a target is achieved, they just want to know its done.

Implementation issues should not be included within the name of methods for that exact reason. The name of the table updated as a result of this method or the technology used has nothing to do in your domain object's method's name.

However from your question it is hard to say what is the exact case at hand.

If you could provide more details perhaps i could provide an additional help.